# How to set custom property of webcontrol be translateable?

Tags: asp.net, localization, web-controls

I have webcontrol which has custom property. The property is set as attribute directly in aspx page.
I use VS.addin "Resource Refactoring Tool" to generate resource files from aspx pages. Working well so far.The thing is it does not pick my custom attributes into translation.
So I am asking, is there any specific attribute to set on my custom property?

this is how I do specify property in code:

```
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [Description("Set the title to be displayed at the top of menu.")]
    public string MenuTitle { get; set; }
```

this is how I specify it at aspx page:
    uc1:GenericMenu ID="gmnBackToShop" runat="server" MenuKey="backToShop" MenuTitle="Back to Shop"

Any help,tips most welcome. Thanks X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, you need to apply the `Localizable` attribute too.

Comment: I just could not see it, even I was looking for simialar words. Thanks anyway.